# How can I make my own double colon path in a blade component?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

When using a laravel mailable with mark down syntax [laravel references](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#writing-the-message) using a double colon syntax which is mapped to the `'views/vendor/mail'` folder.

How can I define this double colon shorthand in my own application?

e.g.

```
@component('mail::button') // Laravels built in mail shorthand
    some text
@endcomponent

@component('mobile::button') // Shorthand I defined myself
    some text
@endcomponent
```

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [loadViewsFrom](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.html#method_loadViewsFrom) in your service provider boot method.

```
$this->loadViewsFrom('path', 'namespace');
```

After that, you will be able to use **namesapce::view** in your blade files.